# Postgres - how to tell when the last VACUUM FULL was run?

Tags: postgresql

If I run the following

```
VACUUM myTable;
```

this gets recorded in the postgres system tables and can be seen with

```
select last_vacuum, vacuum_count from pg_stat_all_tables where relname= 'mytable';
```

However, doing a `VACUUM FULL` seems to go unrecorded.

How can I tell when the last `VACUUM FULL` was run against a table?

Comment: A vacuum full rewrites the table to a new file so logically that table has never been vacuumed full, the previous incarnation was?? If you really want to know you can record the filenode for a table and check when it changed. I can't see why you would wan t to know this information though ?

Answer (score 9):

PostgreSQL doesn't track that information.